# Can you do gauge theories over topological groups?

Tags: quantum-field-theory, mathematical-physics, gauge-theory, group-theory, research-level

Quantum gauge theories involve (functional) integration over a Lie group. Is there any meaningful generalisation to (non-manifold) [topological groups](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Topological_group)?

Consider for example the Whitehead tower
$$
\cdots \to \mathrm{Fivebrane}(N) \to \mathrm{String}(N) \to \mathrm{Spin}(N) \to \mathrm{SO}(N) \to \mathrm{O}(N).
$$

The last three groups are Lie, and they lead to well-defined QFT's. By untwisting $\mathrm{Spin}(N)$ one gets $\mathrm{String}(N)$, which is defined as the cover with trivial $\pi_3$ (and so it is *not* a Lie group). Can one do functional integration over this group? Does it lead to a well-defined and physically reasonable theory?

I guess that, at the perturbative level, all groups in the tower are essentially equivalent. But [higher homotopy groups do play a role in gauge theory](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/419941/84967), and so the different groups are not equivalent at the non-perturbative level. For example, by going from $\mathrm{Spin}(N)$ to $\mathrm{String}(N)$, one loses instantons. Is this correct?

Comment: This might be a *very silly* question and caused by some very basic misunderstanding, but let me ask it anyway: if I understand correctly, in gauge theories the gauge potential is a Lie-algebra valued differential form. In fact it is the pullback of a connection form on a principal $G$-bundle by a section (gauge choice) and such a connection form is $\mathfrak{g}$-valued. If the group is not a Lie group, where the gauge potential would take values on?