# Infinite dimensional gauge theories

Tags: quantum-field-theory, gauge-theory, group-theory, lie-algebra

Gauge theories depend on finite-dimensional symmetry groups like $SU(2)$. Is it possible to construct sensible gauge theories (or at least something similar in spirit) in QFT based on [infinite dimensional Lie groups](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lie_group#Infinite-dimensional_Lie_groups)? If it is possible, is it possible to write down a Lagrangian for such a theory? If it is not possible, why not?

Comment: Definitely possible to write a Lagrangian (take a countably infinite-dimensional algebra such as the Affine Lie algebra etc. and just write the usual Yang-Mills Lagrangian). However, quantization becomes highly non-trivial. Probably related: the large $N$ limit of $SU(N)$ Yang-Mills.

Comment: similar question, no answer: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/439087/84967

Comment: [SU(∞) Yang Mills](https://doi.org/10.1063/1.528788) is detailed in the last section. Recall the PB algebra is essentially SU(∞).

Comment: @CosmasZachos Is PB = 'Poisson Bracket' here? Also, since you appear to have written several papers on this topic, feel free to contribute an answer :)

Comment: Yes, the Poisson Bracket algebra is well-known to be *su(∞)* . Developing the formalism to describe infinite-dimensional matrices as a toroidal "color sheet" and defining the corresponding gauge theory is outlined in [this question](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/66124/relations-between-diffeomorphism-symmetry-theories-and-invariant-sun-n-righ) but you'll have to be more precise/limited in your question.

Comment: Thanks @CosmasZachos, I'll have a look at the linked question.